# RecyclerView displaying wrong Images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-networking

The following is the code for the adapter I'm using to display movie items that contain Movie Images and Movie Titles.

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {

    private List<Movie> movieList;

    public MovieAdapter(List<Movie> movieList) {
        this.movieList = movieList;
    }

    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false);
        return new MovieViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
        holder.mv_name.setText(movie.getName());
        class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                URL url = createUrl(strings[0]);
                Log.v("stringurl", strings[0]);
                try {
                    bitmap = makeHttpRequest(url);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                holder.mv_img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            private URL createUrl(String StringUrl) {
                URL url = null;

                try {
                    url = new URL(StringUrl);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    return null;
                }

                return url;
            }

            private Bitmap makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                InputStream stream = null;
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                    //Log.v("image:",bitmap.toString());
                    return bitmap;
                } catch (IOException e) {

                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
                    if (stream != null) stream.close();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }
        }
        new ImageDownloadTask().execute(movie.getImg());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movieList == null ? 0 : movieList.size();
    }

    class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mv_img;
        TextView mv_name;

        public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mv_img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mv_img);
            mv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mv_name);
        }
    }
}
```

While scrolling down images are loading images of other movies are displaying. For example, for a movie, another movie image is getting displayed and after a second also another movie image is getting displayed in that way after a series of different images correct image is getting displayed.

I'm downloading images from the Url I get from the response inBindViewHolder method.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: use the async task class in the activity or use glide/picasso /... to load the image..

Comment: in `onBindViewHolder()` initially use a placeholder, so you will not see wrong image. Please use `Glide` for loading images as Google recommend to use it

Comment: How should I use a placeholder??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem**

The thing here is to realize that the ViewHolders are pool of reused objects and as you scroll a reused ViewHolder will appear and the previously loaded in it image will be shown.

By using Picasso or Glide or similar you are saving incredible amount of code also using additional features like cache and effects.

**Solution**

First you can use a library like Picasso

`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

then in your recyclerview on bind viewholder

```
Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(holder.imageView);
Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load("http://image.com/image.png").into(holder.imageView);
```

The first line of code will stop any previous images from loading.
The second line will load the current image.

Replace `"http://image.com/image.png"` with your image url. It takes String, URL, etc...

Read more about Picasso [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: This is an alternate solution . But why his approach will not work

Comment: His approach will work. But for the sake of clean code and optimization I gave you the above.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The root cause for your problem is that the bitmap is retrieved after the view has been recycled and thus you get a mismatch when you use it.

**How to resolve**

- The short answer is to use an image caching library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). These libraries where designed to do exactly what you are trying to accomplish.
- Another option is to try to do this on your own. What you can do is save the URL inside the holder and call `setImageBitmap()` only in case the current URL matches the one you just fetched. To save the URL, just add a URL field in MovieViewHolder and store the URL whenever you retrieve the image and check that it matches when you finish downloading.

Comment: How should I check current URL with the one fetched?Can u elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) Library to display images in [RecyclerView](https://11zon.com/android/android_recyclerview.php)

Answer (score 0):

i had also searched for this solution and from Doron Yakovlev-Golani answer i made a solution for my own, as my reputation is low so i'm unable to add a comment.  Below is my solution, here when i added an image in ImageView I also added a ContentDescription to the ImageView as a reference for future use to determine which image need to show when ViewHolder call. The ContentDescription is current ListView position as String.
Here is two condition, first one for checking image previously added or not, if image not added previously, I added the image. second one image already added in the ImageView, so I checking which image need to load by calling ImageView ContentDescription, if ContentDescription matched current position it means i need to add current positions image to ImageView from my list.

**In your onViewHolder you can use like this:**

```
//checking it is first time or not
    if (holder.mv_img.getContentDescription() == null) {
        //adding current position for loading current position image
        imageView.setContentDescription(position + "");
    }
    if (holder.mv_img.getContentDescription().equals(position + "")) {
        holder.mv_img.setImageBitmap(userLogoUri);
    }
```